# Reduction procedure for MethodReference Expressions

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, method-reference, jls

Consider the following article from JLS that describes the reduction procedure for the MethodReference expressions during Type Inference process-:

> A constraint formula of the form ‹MethodReference → T›, where T mentions at least one inference variable, is reduced as follows:
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, if the method reference is exact (§15.13.1), then let P1, ..., Pn be the parameter types of the function type of T, and let F1, ..., Fk be the parameter types of the potentially applicable method. The constraint reduces to a new set of constraints, as follows:
>
> – In the special case where n = k+1, the parameter of type P1 is to act as the target reference of the invocation. The method reference expression necessarily has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier. The constraint reduces to ‹P1 <: ReferenceType› and, for all i (2 ≤ i ≤ n), ‹Pi → Fi-1›.
>
> In all other cases, n = k, and the constraint reduces to, for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), ‹Pi → Fi›.

Here I would like to know some example cases on how the formation of the following are assumed and fitted in the clauses:

- Generic Function type
- Generic Class type (whose method will be used as reference)
- Generic method type (that will be used as a reference)

For example - below are my questions based on the interpretation:

- `P1, ..., Pn` be the **parameter types of the function type of T**, and let `F1, ..., Fk` be the **parameter types of the potentially applicable method.**
- Here I am assuming that the formation takes shape like:

```
FunctionType<P1,P2 ... Pn> funType = ClassCls::MethodRef;
...
class ClassCls {
...
 public static <F1, ..., Fk> RetType potentiallyApplicbMethod(...){}
}
```

- now when we take the case of `n=k+1`

  - Why will **FunctionType** have more number of arguments than the `potentiallyApplicbMethod`?
  - Why is `P1 is to act as the target reference of the invocation`? I guess here P1 is assumed to be the return type (`RetType`) of the `potentiallyApplicbMethod`?
- for the case when `n=k`

  - I assume this is given as when all types specified in **FunctionType** (may or may not include the return type) matches exactly with all the types specified for `potentiallyApplicbMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why will `FunctionType` have more number of arguments than the `potentiallyApplicbMethod`?

There are different forms of method references. One of the forms is `ReferenceType::InstanceMethod`, or as the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) call it, "reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type".

Example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this is a "reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type"
        BiConsumer<Main, String> bar = Main::foo;
    }

    private <T> void foo(T t) {

    }
}
```

Clearly, the function type of `BiConsumer` has 2 parameters, but `foo` only has one. The extra first parameter of the function type is needed because you need an instance to call `foo`, and we haven't specified that instance in the method reference `Main::foo`. `bar.accept(new Main(), "foo")` would be the same as calling `new Main().foo("foo")`. This is what the JLS meant by "target reference" - it's the object on which you call the method. It has nothing to do with return types.

Now you should also be able to see why the JLS says that the method reference in the n=k+1 case must be of the form `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`, as opposed to, say, `Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`.

> for the case when n=k I assume this is given as when all types specified in `FunctionType` matches exactly with all the types specified for potentiallyApplicbMethod?

No, this case just refers to the other kinds of method references:

- Reference to a static method
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object
- Reference to a constructor of a class or array

Comment: `‹P1 <: ReferenceType› and, for all i (2 ≤ i ≤ n), ‹Pi → Fi-1›` for this statement - it is not mandatory that it is always P1 that satisfies the condition - but it can be ANY of the `Px` that satisfies the condition - but there will be exactly 1 `Px` that satisfies this - am I correct here?

Comment: by condition I mean the fact that only the 1st argument (`P1`) can represent the **target reference** ie `‹P1 <: ReferenceType›` and none other `Px` can represent the **target reference** (where `x>1`)

Comment: I think it shouldn't have been bound to P1 alone as if I have an interface defined in this form : `interface Fun<S,T,K> {
  void apply2(S s,T t);
}` - then clearly I can use `K` as the **target reference** right?

Comment: @theutonium.18 Okay, so I understood correctly the first time :) It is only `P1` that can be the target reference. `‹P1 <: ReferenceType› and, for all i (2 ≤ i ≤ n), ‹Pi → Fi-1›` is just listing what constraint formulas a method reference constraint should be reduced to. It doesn't have much to do with target references.

Comment: @theutonium.18 No you can't use `K` as the target reference. Only `S` can be. If you think you succeeded, show me :)

Comment: Please check this one `import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiConsumer<Main, String> bar = Main::foo;
    Fun<String,Double,Main> barrs = Main::foos;
    barrs.apply2("Hey",2.3);
  }

  private <T> void foo(T t) {}
  private static <S,T> void foos(S s,T t) {}
}

interface Fun<S,T,K> {
  void apply2(S s,T t);
}`

Comment: @theutonium.18 Also note that it is not about the order of the type parameters in the interface declaration. It is about the order of the parameters in the single abstract method declaration.

Comment: @theutonium.18 `foos` is a static method. This is not even the `n=k+1` case...

Comment: Yeah .. I realized my folly :P thanks a lot!